# Stop function if interval is set - jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
 var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 1000) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }
        r.redrawSlider()
    }, 50);
}),
```

> **Stop the following script until interval is done**

```
 $(".slider-wrap").mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).find(".slide-desc").css({
        left: '0'
    });
    $(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({
        'padding-left': '100px'
    });
    $(this).find(".slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({
        'left': '0'
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).find(".slide-desc").css({
        left: '-200px'
    });
    $(this).find(".bx-wrapper").css({
        'padding-left': '0'
    });
    $(this).find(".slide-desc p, .slide-desc span, .slide-desc h2").css({
        'left': '500px'
    });
    setTimeout(function() {
        r.redrawSlider();
    },
```

I would like to freeze the above script until interval is done. How can i do that ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't have a sleep/halt method you can use to halt the execution. You have to use `setInterval(...)` or `setTimeout(...)` to emulate the sleep method.

In this case, you can put the code you want to be executed in a function and then call that function when the interval is done.

If you meant when you clear the interval you want to run the code, you should use

```
var startTime = new Date().getTime();
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        if (new Date().getTime() - startTime > 1000) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            //**call your method here**
            thisIsAMethodThatHasYourCode();
            return;
        }
        r.redrawSlider()
    }, 50);
}),
...

function thisIsAMethodThatHasYourCode() {
    $(".slider-wrap").mouseenter(function() {
    .....
}
```

Comment: I want to disable this function when the interval is executing. Stop it for the time when interval is running.

Comment: what's wrong with the answer I provided? Doesn't it stop the code from executing until the interval is cleared?

Comment: $('.slider-wrap').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave'); - only this one before r.redrawSlider(); is missing :)

thx for the help !

Comment: I didn't understand that you wanted to unbind the event handlers. cheers for finding it out yourself.